# Clear Divs drawn with Google Chart chart.draw() method

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I'm working with Google Chart. After drawing some Pie Charts on some divs, I want to clear the canvas where I've drawn the Chart.

Here is the complete code: http://plnkr.co/edit/f6nIBj5o9aawxClZUQjf?p=preview

What I want to happen is that when I select "2014" in the top down menu, all the PieCharts disappear so that only the 2014 chart shows.

I've already tried using `document.getElementById('div').clear` and 
`document.getElementById('div').remove` but both don't work:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('method-select');
  canvas.onchange = function(){
      if(this.value == 'TimeSeriesComparison'){
        loadData(1965, 'div');
        loadData(1975, 'div1');
        loadData(1985, 'div2');
        loadData(1995, 'div3');
        loadData(2005, 'div4');
        loadData(2014, 'div5');  
      }else{
        canvas.clear;
        loadData(2014, 'div');  
      }
  };
```

on

```
<body>
<select id="method-select">
    <option value="TimeSeriesComparison" selected>Time Series Comparison</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
 <div class="container">
  <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="div" style="float: left;"></div>
    <div id="div1" style="margin-left: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="float:left"></div>
    <div id="div3" style="margin-left: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="div4" style="float: left;"></div>
    <div id="div5" style="margin-left: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="div6" style="float:left"></div>
  </div>
```

but the charts don't get cleared...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be good for you:

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jygFggpn7GSv5pJzflYb?p=preview)

add class: class="charts" load and clear divs:

```
      loadData(this.value, 'div');
      var charts = document.getElementsByClassName("charts");
      for (i=0; i<= charts.length; i++) {
        charts[i].innerHTML = "";
      }
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the easiest/fastest approach:

Use CSS to hide the particular `<div>`s

The CSS:

```
 div.container>div.foo>div:nth-child(1n+2){display:none;}
```

...it will hide all(except the first) child-divs of the first div in `div.container`, when this first div does have the class `foo`.

All you have to do now ist to add or remove this className to this div:

```
    if (this.value == 'TimeSeriesComparison') {
      document.querySelector('.container>div').className='';

      loadData(1965, 'div');
      loadData(1975, 'div1');
      loadData(1985, 'div2');
      loadData(1995, 'div3');
      loadData(2005, 'div4');
      loadData(2014, 'div5');
    } 
    else { 
     document.querySelector('.container>div').className='foo';

      loadData(2014, 'div');
    }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uPHlHdSZ9iRmWjKlmuoz?p=preview